# What does “treat something with caution” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the phrase “treat something with caution” mean?

Comment: err ... what is sth?

Comment: something. english teachers use it here in middle europe

Comment: Looks from the context like an abbreviation for "something", but I've never seen it before.

Comment: so: "what does phrase threat something with caution" mean?

Comment: Here on ELU people have been asked to help maintain site standards by avoiding using 'sth'. We also capitalise Europe.

Comment: If you look up 'caution' in a dictionary, it should be obvious what the phrase means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To treat something with caution means to act carefully around it, usually because it may be dangerous.

Comment: While this is true good answers on ELU are expected to be definitive and supported with the appropriate references.